# how to retrieve date and show in input (type="Date") using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using this code to retrieve data from the database by using ajax all data was returned successfully but the date was not shown in the input (type="date") I have done a lot of research and implementation but still have not succeeded follo

```
function EditHoliday(id) {
        debugger;
        var url = "/RoketChat/editHoliday?Id=" + id;
        $("#editHolidays").modal();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#id").val(obj.Id);
                $("#HolidayName").val(obj.Name); 
                $("#StartDate").val(obj.StartDate);
                $("#EndDate").val(obj.EndDate);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: what value do you get in `obj.StartDate` ?

Comment: I think `StartDate` must be a `string` in format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @Chetan 11-11-2022 12:00:00AM

Comment: @sallushan StartDate is in datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using following Code we can retrieve the date and show it in input type="date"

```
 const a = new Date(obj.StartDate);
                const formattedDate = a.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (a.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + a.getDate()).slice(-2)
                $("#StartDate").val(formattedDate);

                const b = new Date(obj.EndDate);
                const formattedEndDate = b.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (b.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + b.getDate()).slice(-2)
                $("#EndDate").val(formattedEndDate);
```